# why youtube_upload is giving xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError in python 2.7 on linux

Tags: python-2.7, youtube-api, gdata-api

I am new to python and while searching i found that i can upload a video to youtube in command line in linux and i am using centos 5.7

i first installed python 2.7 and face many problems in doing it but i search it on google and find answers

one main problem had faced and solved the httpsconnection and after installing the open ssl and openssl-devel it is ok
i am using this command in order to Upload the video:

`>python youtube_upload.py --email="test.for.utube@gmail.com" --password="****" --title="test" --category="test" test.mp4`

and getting this result:

```
Login to Youtube API: email='test.for.utube@gmail.com', password='********' Traceback (most recent call last):

File "youtube_upload.py", line 449, in <module>

sys.exit(catch_exceptions(EXIT_CODES, main_upload, sys.argv[1:]))

File "youtube_upload.py", line 105, in catch_exceptions
fun(*args, **kwargs)

File "youtube_upload.py", line 381, in main_upload
captcha_response=options.captcha_response)

File "youtube_upload.py", line 183, in login
self.categories = self.get_categories()

File "youtube_upload.py", line 255, in get_categories
xml = ElementTree.XML(xmldata)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1301, in XML
parser.feed(text)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1643, in feed
self._raiseerror(v)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1507, in _raiseerror
raise err

xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: syntax error: line 1, column 49
```

and didn't find any solution on google.
so I hope that anyone can help me to successfully complete the youtube upload through the command line.

Thanks at all. and if I can have a fast reply about the time expected to have a solution so i know how much should i wait

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what `youtube_upload.py` is, but if you're looking for a "canonical" Python command line script that supports YouTube uploads (and supports OAuth 2 for authorization), try http://code.google.com/p/googlecl/